# smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused Authentication Error in Flask App

Tags: python, flask, smtplib

I have created a flask app and whenever I use the forgot password module I get this error

I have used this code in my **init**.py file

```
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category ='info'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']= 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']=True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
mail = Mail(app)
```

The error
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError d16sm4144946pgb.4 - gsmtp', 'noreply@demo.com')

Comment: did you read documentation in your link ? it seems you use wrong login or password. Maybe first use `print(app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])` to see what values you use.

Comment: @furas It says to enable IMAP in gmail, I have already done it and applying what you have suggested the MAIL_USERNAME is my primary email, but I am still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']= 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']=True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

To:

```
app.config.update(
MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com',
MAIL_PORT='587',
MAIL_USE_TLS=True,
MAIL_USERNAME=os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER'),
MAIL_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
)
```

And don't forget to turn on less secure apps: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

on my server, app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']='True' is work. It's string but not bool in this params.